# Conditional UI actions

Tags: cypress

I am writing a cypress test and trying to figure out a case when I could perform actions based on whether the splash screen appears or not.

Eg:

```
   it('Test 2',()=>{
       if(cy.get('#center-tile-banner-popup'))
       {
          cy.get('[title="Accept Cookies"]').click();
       }
       cy.get('.media-object ').click(10, 10);
    })
```

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things with your code,

- `cy.get()` doesn't return a boolean for `if()` to check, so you can't use it there.
- `cy.get()` fails the test if the selector isn't found, so if the splash screen is not present the last line will not be executed.

One way to test for a selector without failing is to use JQuery, which supplied on the global `Cypress.$()`.

Here's a sample test to illustrate,

**HTML**

```html
<div class="maybe"></div>
<div class="anotherDiv"></div>
```

**Spec**

```js
before(() => {
    cy.visit('/app/conditional-execution.html')
})

it('conditional execution - element found', () => {
  cy.get('div.maybe')  // fails test and stops here if not found

  const $element = Cypress.$('div.maybe')  // non-failing check, returns JQuery object
  const exists = !!$element.length;        // convert JQuery object to a boolean

  console.log('Element found?', exists);

  if (exists) {
    // Conditional commands
  } 

  // Commands to execute if found or not
  cy.get('div.anotherDiv')  

})

it('conditional execution - element not found', () => {
  const $element = Cypress.$('div.maybeNot')  // non-failing check, returns JQuery object
  const exists = !!$element.length;           // convert JQuery object to a boolean

  console.log('Element found?', exists);

  if (exists) {
    // Conditional commands
  } 

  // Commands to execute if found or not
  cy.get('div.anotherDiv')  

})
```

This would be your syntax

```js
if(Cypress.$('#center-tile-banner-popup').length) {
  cy.get('[title="Accept Cookies"]').click();
}
```

Comment: although this answer is correct, @poojya-sankar why don't you have control over the state of your application?

it sounds like those should be two tests, one to check for the splash screen and another to bypass the splash screen and test whatever comes next

Comment: @JosePita that's a valid point, made it myself before. Why don't you submit an answer based on that?

Comment: the problem is that sometimes QAs/testers don't have full working knowledge or access to the application (test consultants and companies), hence my question before assuming that is true

Comment: @JosePita yes I see. I read your comment as control of the test data, ie. fixtures/stubbing, to control when the splash screen appears. Likely there's also a way to make the app more deterministic and testable.

Comment: yeah, if you (qa/tester) work directly with the development team it's quite easy (set a cookie or token and bypass the splash screen)

Comment: Richard Matsen Thanks for the answer. 
@JosePita I had to use this when I use chrome as the browser default for the test, the splash screen's visibility was really flaky. I switched to electron because there was XHR looping and it seems to be more reliable as the splash screen seems to come on everytime.

Comment: what controls the appearing or not of the splash screen? in my app we have an onboarding popup on the first time we access the app, then once we go through it there's a localStorage variable set so it doesn't show anymore. What I do is to test that it shows on the first time (1st test) and then on a different test set the localStorage variable and check that it does NOT show (2nd test).

would this be doable on your side?